# how to use featuretools get_pandas_data_slice

Tags: featuretools

Can someone show an example or give some more explanation around how to use featuretools.EntitySet.get_pandas_data_slice()?  I've looked at the API documentation but am unclear on the parameters *filter_entity_ids, index_eid,* and *instances*

Specifically, I want to filter my entity set to a subset, and this method looks promising.

Comment: can you add some details about the type of subset you're looking to create? this function could be helpful – Max Kanter 16 mins ago